# Android how to pass a variable to another java file

Tags: android, variables

In Reminder1.java I have the int *hourOfDay2* and int *minute2* variables. These equals with the *hourOfDay* and *minute* variable of the TimePickerDialog.
In myfile.java i want to examine the value of these variables. How to do that?

Comment: [Start here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) -- happy coding.

Comment: You need to explain more. Do you have an instance of the Reminder1 class in your myfile class? Are they static ints? Are either of these classes Activities or extending some other Android class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing I've seen posted here on SO a few times, and that I've used for global variables, is an extended Application class, like so:

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {
    private static int hourOfDay2;
    private static int minute2;

    public static int getHourOfDay() {
        return hourOfDay2;
    }

    public static int getMinute() {
        return minute2;
    }

    public static void setHourOfDay(int hour) {
        hourOfDay2 = hour;
    }

    public static void setMinute(int minute) {
        minute2 = minute;
    }
}
```

Add it to your Application tag in the manifest, like so:

`<application android:name=".GlobalVars" />`

Then, in your main class's onCreate, or wherever necessary, just call `GlobalVars.setMinute(int)` to initialize them, then you can access them the same way in any other class, with `int x = GlobalVars.getMinute()`.

Comment: @Jems: Heh, yeah most likely. I don't have Eclipse at the moment, so it slipped my mind. :) fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In android, you can use [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass values.